# Python py7zr can't list files in archive - how to read 7z archive without extracting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, 7zip, py7zr

I tried to list all files inside 7z archive (I don't want to extract them).

I followed the documentation of the creators of py7zr.

My code look like this:

```
def checkArchive(archivePath):
for filename in os.listdir(archivePath):
    print("Filename is: " + filename)
    cmd = "py7zr l " + filename
    os.system(cmd)
```

I also tried `cmd = python -m "py7zr l " + filename` as a cmd command.

But no matter what command I use, the program always returns an error: `not a 7z file`.

I made sure and I know that all files on which the command operates have the extension `7z`.

How can I get py7zr to start recognizing the file type? Or is there any other way to list the `7z`archive?

Answer (score 1):

I think can use this to list files in a 7z archive.

```
import py7zr

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(r'<PATH TO 7Z FILE>.7z', 'r') as archive:
    all_paths = archive.getnames()
```